# Assistance requested to refactor a section of Typescript code for readability

Tags: javascript, typescript

Code

```
if (source.length > 0) {
    if (
        source[0].mandatory === true &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType !== "mandatory"
    ) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    } else if (
        source[0].mandatory === false &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory"
    ) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
} else {
    if (
        target[0].mandatory === true &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory"
    ) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    } else if (
        target[0].mandatory === false &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType !== "mandatory"
    ) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
}
```

All is working, the problem I have is that this code is not very readable. Can someone please help me refactor this?

Thanks

Comment: I would leave it as is since there are already answers here, but in the future it would benefit reviewers to have a bit more information about the code in the description. From [the help center page _How to ask_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask): "_You will get more insightful reviews if you not only provide your code, but also give an explanation of what it does. The more detail, the better._"

Comment: We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much javascript or typescript. But this seems to be a basic problem.

So, I will give it a try in phased manner:

> Level 1: Clean up, by merging conditions

```
if (source.length > 0) {
    if ((source[0].mandatory === true &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType !== "mandatory") || 
        (source[0].mandatory === false &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory"))
    {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
} else {
    if ((target[0].mandatory === true &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory") ||
        (target[0].mandatory === false &&
        this.allInputs.documentsType !== "mandatory"))
    {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
}
```

> Level 2: Merging more aggressively

```
if ((source.length > 0 && ((source[0].mandatory === true &&
    this.allInputs.documentsType !== "mandatory") || 
    (source[0].mandatory === false &&
    this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory"))) ||
    ((target[0].mandatory === true &&
    this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory") ||
    (target[0].mandatory === false &&
    this.allInputs.documentsType !== "mandatory"))) 
{
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

> Level 3: Using generic type variable, to clean up repeating conditions
> **Edit:** I would have liked to simply this more but this assumes both `source` and `target` to be same which are not.

```
var obj = null;
if (source.length > 0) {
    obj = source[0];
} else {
    obj = target[0];
}

if ((obj.mandatory === true &&
    this.allInputs.documentsType !== "mandatory") ||
    (obj.mandatory === false &&
    this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory"))
{
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

I hope you understand what I am suggesting you to do.

Edit: As correctly suggested by Scott my last optimization is wrongly treating `source` and `target` as same, please pardon my mistake.

Comment: I think there's a bug in your final revision. Looking closely, the o.p. doesn't treat source[0].mandatory exactly the same as target[0].mandatory. e.g. The o.p. checks `source[0].mandatory === true && documentType !== 'mandatory'`, which is different from th other check `target[0].mandatory === true && documentType === 'mandatory'`

Comment: Oh.. yes thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You should comment the actual code block to point out earlier that there's a bug, before readers have a chance to get hung up on it themselves.  Don't just leave an "edit: previous stuff was wrong" at the bottom, that's not nearly as good.  You could present that 3rd version as "you'd like your code to look something like this if possible, but this actually implements slightly different logic".

Comment: `this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory"` and `!==` are inverses of each other, right?  So you can presumably use `obj.mandatory` to invert the compare result or not, or check `mandatory != (compare)` or something.  In fact that's what Scotty Jamison's answer is doing.

Comment: Yes, I agree Scotty's answer is more refined. Also, I have added the suggested comment on top.

Answer (score 11):

To make it easier to follow the flow of the logic, I'm just going to pull out the longer parts of these conditions into helper variables. They may not stay like that in the final version, but it helps as I'm revising it.

```javascript
const isDocumentTypeMandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === 'mandatory';

if (source.length > 0) {
    const mandatory = source[0].mandatory;
    if (mandatory === true && !isDocumentTypeMandatory) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    } else if (mandatory === false && isDocumentTypeMandatory ) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
} else {
    const mandatory = target[0].mandatory;
    if (mandatory === true && isDocumentTypeMandatory) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    } else if (mandatory === false && !isDocumentTypeMandatory) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
}
```

The trick to simplifying these kinds of things is to figure out what is similar, figure out how to change the code to make those parts exactly the same, then DRY it up.

For example, I'm noticing that the two branches of the outer if-else are almost exactly the same. The only differences are where it gets the mandatory variable from, and the `!` that is sometimes in front of isDocumentTypeMandatory.

Lets start by extracting out the diferences from the two branches:

```javascript
const isDocumentTypeMandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === 'mandatory';
const mandatory = source.length > 0 ? source[0].mandatory : target[0].mandatory;
const sourceHasContent = source.length > 0;

if (source.length > 0) {
    if (mandatory === true && isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    } else if (mandatory === false && isDocumentTypeMandatory === sourceHasContent) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
} else {
    if (mandatory === true && isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    } else if (mandatory === false && isDocumentTypeMandatory === sourceHasContent) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
}
```

Now those the two branches of the outer-if are now exactly the same, which lets me just get rid of it.

```javascript
const isDocumentTypeMandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === 'mandatory';
const mandatory = source.length > 0 ? source[0].mandatory : target[0].mandatory;
const sourceHasContent = source.length > 0;

if (mandatory === true && isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent) {
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
} else if (mandatory === false && isDocumentTypeMandatory === sourceHasContent) {
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

At this point, we can just combine the two conditions into one. I personally prefer avoiding multiline if conditions and instead extract the condition into an external variable.

```javascript
const isDocumentTypeMandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === 'mandatory';
const mandatory = source.length > 0 ? source[0].mandatory : target[0].mandatory;
const sourceHasContent = source.length > 0;

const flipMandatoryValue = (
    (mandatory === true && isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent) ||
    (mandatory === false && isDocumentTypeMandatory === sourceHasContent)
);

if (flipMandatoryValue) {
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

This is probably about as good as it'll get. Certainly, the variable naming can be a ton better (without much context, its hard to give them good names).

---

There is one other trick that can be applied to simplify things even further, but there's already so much going on here that it might just make the code even less readable, but I'll present it anyways.

This whole time I've been assuming that `mandatory` can take on other values besides "true" or "false", which is why you're explicitly checking if they're `=== true` or `=== false`. In the following revisions, I'll preserve this idea by doing a typeof check. I'll then modify the condition as follows:

```javascript
const flipMandatoryValue = typeof mandatory === 'boolean' && (
    (mandatory && isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent) ||
    (!mandatory && isDocumentTypeMandatory === sourceHasContent)
);

// is the same as
const subCondition = isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent;
const flipMandatoryValue = typeof mandatory === 'boolean' && (
    (mandatory && subCondition) ||
    (!mandatory && !subCondition)
);

// is the same as
const subCondition = isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent;
const flipMandatoryValue = typeof mandatory === 'boolean' && (
    // Either both of these booleans should be true, or both should be false,
    // so we can just compare them to each other with ===.
    mandatory === subCondition
);

// is the same as
const subCondition = isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent;
// We can drop the typeof check - we're comparing with a boolean anyways
const flipMandatoryValue = mandatory === subCondition;
```

This gives us the final revision as follows:

```
const isDocumentTypeMandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === 'mandatory';
const mandatory = source.length > 0 ? source[0].mandatory : target[0].mandatory;
const sourceHasContent = source.length > 0;
const subCondition = isDocumentTypeMandatory !== sourceHasContent;

if (mandatory === subCondition) {
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

As I said before, using === to compare booleans can be a useful trick to simplify complicated if-thens, but here I feel like it adds more complexity than value, unless you can find good ways to name everything and make it more intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the values of `source[0].mandatory` and `target[0].mandatory` are booleans (`true` or `false`), you can make the code a lot shorter by comparing the truthiness of your expressions:

```js
const docTypeMandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory";
if (source.length > 0) {
    if (source[0].mandatory === !docTypeMandatory) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
} else {
    if (target[0].mandatory === docTypeMandatory) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
}
```

This also helps highlight the flipping of logic between the two main cases, which was otherwise a bit buried.

Comment: The conditions should be reversed: `source[0].mandatory === !docTypeMandatory`

Answer (score 4):

Not a review

Just a point that expressions are preferable over statements. You can use a ternary and test a boolean `source[0].mandatory` or `target[0].mandatory` against a boolean result `this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory"`.

```
const mandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory";
item.mandatory = source.length ?
    (source[0].mandatory !== mandatory ? !item.mandatory : item.mandatory) :
    (target[0].mandatory === mandatory ? !item.mandatory : item.mandatory);
```

Which can be written as statements

```
const mandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory";
if (source.length) {
    if (source[0].mandatory !== mandatory) {
        item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
    }
} else if (target[0].mandatory === mandatory) {
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

or

```
const mandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory";
if (source.length) {
    if (source[0].mandatory !== mandatory) { item.mandatory = !item.mandatory }
} else if (target[0].mandatory === mandatory) { item.mandatory = !item.mandatory }
```

There are even shorter ways to write this, but that will begin to obscure what is happening.

```
const mandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory";
item.mandatory =  (source[0]?.mandatory ?? !target[0].mandatory) !== mandatory ? 
    !item.mandatory : 
    item.mandatory;
```

Comment: I think that logic towards the end is incorrect. Whether the test item in question is source or target inverts the test in consideration.

Comment: @SteveBennett That is why `target[0].mandatory` has a `!` in front of it.

Comment: IMHO, ternaries should only be used in simple cases. Nested ternaries are generally more confusing than nested if/then.

Comment: @Barmar   Your comment IMHO sounds very like doctrine.  I will not insult the intelligence of readers by avoiding standard language features (someone declared confusing). Surely you are not  suggesting there are coders that are confused by code?  I am more than sure you understand ternaries, you know they are easy to read so I ask why are they *"...more confusing..."*? To whom are they *"...more confusing..."* ?  Rhetorical I have heard the less than water tight arguments way too many times. Lets treat readers as professionals, not as 1st year CS undergrads... :)

Comment: I was very clear to preface it as personal opinion. Ternaries are fine, but can be abused like any terse notation.

Answer (score 4):

This is based on [@Steve Bennett's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260959/191231).

- You can skip the `source.length` check using [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).
- Since both the `if` conditions have the same block of code, you can club them together with an `||`

```js
const isDocTypeMandatory = this.allInputs.documentsType === "mandatory";

if (source[0]?.mandatory === !isDocTypeMandatory
    || target[0].mandatory === isDocTypeMandatory) 
{
  item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is starting to get a little bit hairy though, because it relies on the fact that `source[0]?.mandatory` will evaluate to `undefined` and won't match `false`. Which is starting to get less readable again.

Answer (score 2):

I've taken a slightly different approach from what seems to have been answered here, so I decided to add an answer to already good answers.

What you have is a boolean algebra problem, where you have four variables that express a result.

The variables are :

```
sourceIsNonZero = source.length > 0;
sourceIsMandatory = source[0].mandatory === true;
targetIsMandatory = target[0].mandatory === true;
docTypeIsMandatory = documentsType === "mandatory";
```

I've chosen to express the output as : **Should the item's mandatory value be flipped?**

Since there are four boolean variables, we have a possibility of \$2^4=16\$ combinations, which isn't so bad. To try and reduce this boolean, I've decided to use the good old [Truth Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table), which works well for small number of combinations.

[image: Truth table]

Then, we can observe the truth table to find out a boolean expression that summarizes the problem, in this case :

```
(sourceIsNonZero && (sourceIsMandatory !== docTypeIsMandatory)) || (targetIsMandatory === docTypeIsMandatory)
```

Considering this, this is the solution I would propose :

```
sourceIsNonZero = source.length > 0;
sourceIsMandatory = source[0].mandatory === true;
targetIsMandatory = target[0].mandatory === true;
docTypeIsMandatory = documentsType === "mandatory";

shouldMandatoryAttributeBeFlipped = (sourceIsNonZero && (sourceIsMandatory !== docTypeIsMandatory)) 
                                    || (targetIsMandatory === docTypeIsMandatory)

if (shouldMandatoryAttributeBeFlipped) {
    item.mandatory = !item.mandatory;
}
```

**Edit**

I first used `&&` to signify "are the same", which is... dumb from my part. What we want to check isn't that they are both true, but that they are different in the case of the `source` check and the same in the case of the `target` check. I changed `&&` to `===`.

As pointed out in the comments, invoking `source[0].mandatory` if `source < length == 0` will crash, in this case I would either recommend joining the two conditions : `sourceIsNonZeroAndMandatory = source.length > 0 && source[0].mandatory` or use the null propagation operator on the second condition `source[0]?.mandatory`.

**end edit**

While it's a little bit more "wordy" than other propositions, I think this solution is readable, presents in clear manner the important variables and the way the output is decided.

Comment: Most likely you cannot invoke `source[0]` if `source.length` is zero

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე very true. Let me change that

Comment: Nightmare once you want to debug..

Comment: @KorayTugay I can only disagree. With the quality of the debugging tools available and the fact that every condition is clearly named, you'd find very quickly where the problem lies.

Comment: You final deduction is only solving half of the problem - when sourceIsManditory/targetIsManditory === true, but what about when they === false? Take the first row of your truth table for example - It's supposed to result in "true", but your boolean expression would give "false".

Comment: @ScottyJamison Right, thanks for spotting that, I fixed it.